# What is the maximum number of simultaneous I/O operations in .net 4.5?

Tags: c#, multithreading, io

What is the maximum number of files I can write simultaneously using a Multithreaded scenario, using static void, ie:

```
public static void WriteToXmlFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false) where T : new()
{
    TextWriter writer = null;
    try
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, append);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToWrite);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (writer != null)
            writer.Close();
    }
}
```

This static void will be accessed from multiple tasks running simultaneously. Is there any default limit for the number of files I can write at the same time, or any way I can modify any such property?

Comment: Why do you think there is any limitation?

Comment: Well, the amount of files you can write at once at least is fairly easy to test. And I imagine that said limit would come from the OS, rather than .NET

Comment: I would think the limit to be imposed only by the hardware environment.  There is no fixed limit in .NET.  Only load testing would reveal the bottleneck.

Comment: In app.config there is a limit about simultaneous network connections. (Default is 2)
I was thinking if is there any option like this about io activity...

Answer (score -1):

The bottleneck here is going to be in hardware, not in software.  The head on your disk drive can only be in one place at any one time.  It isn't going to work any faster (and it is likely to work slower to to repeatedly seeking to new blocks) if there are multiple threads telling it to do stuff at the same time.

The degree of parallelziation that would be helpful is going to be equal to the number of physical drives that you have.  If you have 4 disk drives, you can benefit from writing out 4 files at once.

And it's of course worth noting that there is no need for more than one thread here, ever, regardless of whether you want to perform parallel writes or not.  You can use *asynchrony* rather than multiple threads to achieve parallelism, if you actually have multiple physical disk drives.

Comment: For example: In app.config there is a limit about simultaneous network connections. If you don;t specify it, the default is 2. I was just wondering about the same thing in io activity...

Comment: @Olsi There is no artificial throttling, no, although, again, if you don't have multiple physical disk drives, you'd probably wish there was.

Comment: The *limitations* are ultimately imposed by the OS (as far as open resources). That being said, if they are hit .. uhh, it's usually a bug like not `Disposing` the files correctly.

Comment: @user2864740 I would strongly suspect that the OS is going to have no problem supporting way more concurrent file streams than you'll be able to come with as far as physical disk drives.  I would imagine it would take thousands, if not more, physical drives to surpass what the OS could handle.  No machine is going to have anywhere near that many drive slots.

Comment: @Servy It is easy to exhaust windows file resources, and there are questions on SO About it. The *limitations* (which exist) are separate from bad performance (which may or may not also exist).

Comment: @Servy Where is "physical drives" coming in? Does not factor to *a finite set of open files* (a limit).

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, the OS is going to limit you to a few thousand concurrent IO operations.  If you want to be writing to more than a few thousand physical drives at once, you won't be able to.

Comment: @user2864740 When you go to the store and buy a hard drive, that's a physical drive.  You'll need one of those for each degree of parallelism you want if you want to write multiple files concurrently.

Comment: Limit: "a point or level beyond which something does not or may not extend or pass", "a restriction on the size or amount of something permissible or possible"

Comment: @user2864740 What's your point?  If the OP is attempting to write out to multiple files at the same time he is most certainly going to be limited by the number of open file streams the OS supports.  That limit will be huge, in the thousands at least, and many other things will bottleneck the writing long before that ever happens, so that limit while it technically exists, isn't actually going to be what determines the degree of parallelism to which he can write out his data.

Comment: Of course there should be a hardware limit. I'm not asking about that. I want to know if there is a limit defined for .NET for a single application...

Comment: @Olsi No, there is not.

Comment: @Servy Is there any documentation about this?

Comment: @Olsi Why would they document the fact that they *didn't* go out of their way to artificially limit something?  They'd document it if they *did* do it.  They don't have documentation of every feature they decided not to provide.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but why on earth this limit should exist for (for example) network connections, and you should specify it, if you want it to be greater then 2?